# How to apply CSS generated by colorzilla to the body element

Tags: css

I have generated this from colorzilla and want to apply it to the body but I get lines. can anyone help me fixing this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/7Qr4m/**

```
body {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%);
 /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(226,226,226,1)));
 /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%);
 /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%);
 /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%);
 /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%);
 /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e2e2e2',GradientType=1 );
 /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, both the `html`/`body` have a height of `0`.

Adding the following will solve this:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qr4m/2/)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```